# Problem with React Hook "useCallback" and Pure components

Tags: performance, react-hooks

Before React Hooks, I had a code like this:

```
interface State {
  f1: number;
  f2: number;
}

class OldClassParent extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      f1: 0,
      f2: 0
    };
  }

  public render() {
    const { f1, f2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {/* Each pure component re-render only if its value has changed (OK) */}
        <MyPureCmp value={f1} name="f1" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <MyPureCmp value={f2} name="f2" onChange={this.onChange} />
      </>
    );
  }

  private onChange = (name: string, newValue: number) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.setState({
      [name]: newValue
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I try to have the same behavior with React-hooks. I made the following:

```
const NewHookParent: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    f1: 0,
    f2: 0
  });

  // useCallback does not help me here
  const onChange = useCallback((name: string, newValue: number) => {
    setState({...state, [name]: newValue});
  }, [state, setState]);

  const { f1, f2 } = state;
  return (
    <>
      {/* Each pure component re-render when any value change 
        as the onChange handler is never the same (NOT OK) */}
      <MyPureCmp value={f1} name="f1" onChange={onChange} />
      <MyPureCmp value={f2} name="f2" onChange={onChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is that I have lost the re-rendering optimization I had before.
In this example, for simplicity, I used only two fields, but actually I may have *any number of fields* (and it can be dynamic, not known at compile time).
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setState` function produced by `useState`, accepts an updater function. The updater is called with the current state. Using this allows replaces passing the state to `useCallback`, and since the `setState` itself won't change, `useCallback` will return the same function all the time.

```
const onChange = useCallback((name: string, newValue: number) => {
  setState(state => ({...state, [name]: newValue}));
}, [setState]);
```